# Tomcat works with port :443 and doesn't with :80 despite of enabling firewall

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat, connector

I have a problem with Tomcat connectors. When I try to connect with SSL it works and I can access the page (https://nombritech.pl). I would like to be able to be redirected from port 80 to 443, but if I try to connect with http I cannot access the page (http://nombritech.pl).

Is something wrong with these connectors I specified? I think I've done everything right like I have seen in other threads.

```
<Connector port="80" redirectPort="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" />
    <Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" KeystoreFile="/opt/tomcat/certificate/nombritech.pl.keystore" keystorePass="pass" />
```

I can't see any traffic going through port 80:

[image]

I'm running this on Ubuntu 17.10 and Tomcat 9 beta 2.

EDIT: I think it may be running on ipv6 instead of ipv4:

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      23950/systemd-resol
tcp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1151/dnsmasq
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      851/vsftpd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19096/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      940/postgres
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5433          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      939/postgres
tcp        0    464 79.137.81.193:22        29.72.22.156:52036      ESTABLISHED 20310/sshd: root@pt
tcp        0    136 79.137.81.193:22        29.72.22.156:53406      ESTABLISHED 27828/sshd: root@no
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      27741/java
tcp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*                    LISTEN      23950/systemd-resol
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      27741/java
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      19096/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      940/postgres
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      27741/java
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*                           23950/systemd-resol
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:54514         127.0.0.1:54514         ESTABLISHED 939/postgres
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           23950/systemd-resol
udp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*                           1151/dnsmasq
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:67              0.0.0.0:*                           1151/dnsmasq
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           740/dhclient
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:58536         127.0.0.1:58536         ESTABLISHED 940/postgres
udp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*                                23950/systemd-resol
```

**EDIT2:** I changed it to tcp but it **still doesn't respond** to http:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      28573/java
```

Port 80 is closed like before. Do you have any ideas what I could do now with it? I would be very grateful for any hints on this matter.

EDIT:  Now it is working if I have connectors with port :8080 and :443, :80 still doesn't work, although it has been enabled in firewall and I'm running Tomcat as root, **why can't I run it on :80 then?** Tomcat listens on port :80 and connection is always refused

EDIT:

My current server.xml:

```
<Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="80" redirectPort="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" address="0.0.0.0"/>
    <Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" KeystoreFile="/opt/tomcat/certificate/nombritech.pl.keystore" keystorePass="pass" />
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
            <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase" />
        </Realm>
        <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"></Host>
    </Engine>
</Service>
```

Comment: You don't appear to have opened port 80 in your firewall. Off topic.

Comment: To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

Comment: @EJP according to sudo ufw status port 80 is open

Comment: According to the connect timeout I just got, and the lack of traffic through port 80 that you oberved, it isn't.

Comment: Hm... why is it possible if ufw states it is allowed? How can I enable it then?

Comment: See my edit, how can I set it to run on ipv4?

Comment: 10 seconds of ***research*** answers that last question: [How does one get tomcat to bind to ipv4 address?](https://serverfault.com/q/390840)

Comment: @Andreas I did it and still no difference... I'm always trying to look for answers before I write something but I could not find that one, sorry if I caused any problems to you and thank you for your help. Do you have any suggestions on this matter if changing it to tcp still doesn't provide any solution?

Comment: Okay, so now it is working if I have connectors with port :8080 and :443, :80 still doesn't work, although it has been enabled in firewall and I'm running Tomcat as root, why can't I run it on :80 then? Tomcat listens on port :80 and connection is always refused

Comment: Please clarify. If it is *refused,* Tomcat isn't listening at port 80: check the logs. If it *times out*, it's still a firewall issue. They aren't the same thing.

Comment: @EJP When I try to connect externally the connection is refused - not timed out it is immediately refused (I tried through browser/telnet), when I try to wget it on the server it runs without problems, On :8080 I do not have any of these problems and I checked many times if port :80 is open in my firewall and it is. Netstat shows that Tomcat is running on port :80 and :443 on tcp... I don't know what's going on I have been struggling with this for a last few days... seen everythings whats on the web on this subject

Comment: My problem is very similar to this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/port-80-is-accessible-through-localhost-but-the-connection-is-refused-externally

Comment: I get 'connection refused' too. That is progress: it means your firewall is now open. Does `netstat` still show `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN` for the `java` process?

Comment: @EJP yes it's exactly that

Comment: Is `79.137.81.193` (IP address of nombritech.pl) a local address of the server host? If not, do you have a firewall forwarding rule from `79.137.81.193:80` to the server's internal IP address:80?

Comment: No, I think I don't have any such rule... I have no forwardings rules at the moment, but why :443 works normally then?

Comment: I have no idea, and I know nothing about IPTables, sorry, but if you need such a rule and you don't have one, that's the problem. But you haven't answered my first question.

Comment: hostname -I shows me that: "79.137.81.193 192.168.122.1" I guess it's what you asked for, sorry I'm not into this network subjects too much :( I guess I would have to forward it to 192.168.122.1:80?

Comment: No, you don't, because it is a local address of the server host. In fact you can't.

Comment: Okay, thanks and do you think that If I have a host in server.xml which name is localhost it affects in anyway this connection? Maybe it's something I should change there if it's not that? I posted it in the last edit

Comment: No. The only things that matter are the port and the localAddress in the Connector.

Comment: @EJP I have no idea what I could do more now about it :( And I don't know why :8080 works and :80 doesn't, it's very strange... I've read something about permissions but I'm running Tomcat as root and it shouldn't be an issue more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled my Ubuntu Server and now it works as expected. I don't know the exact cause of this problem, but it must have been an issue with firewall or other network related things as the Tomcat configuration remained the same as before.

Thank you for help on this matter, I'm happy it started to work :). I wish I knew why it hadn't been working.